# Convergence parameter: Find the value of $p>0$ for which the series converge

Tags: calculus, convergence-divergence

For the sum for $k=2$ to infinity: $$\frac{\ln k}{k^p}\ $$

The textbook says the answer is $p>1$.

Comment: look for Bertrand criterion :
http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/S%C3%A9ries_de_Bertrand
(couldn't find a link in English, sorry)

Comment: Here you have one :)
http://www.sosmath.com/calculus/series/bertrand/bertrand.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $a_n=\frac{\log n}{n^p}$.

Being $a_n\geq0$ and not increasing, we can use Cauchy Condensation Criterion: $\sum_{n}a_n$ converges iff $\sum_n2^na_{2^n}$ converges.

Now $2^na_{2^n}=2^n\frac{n\log2}{2^{np}}=\frac{n\log2}{(2^{(p-1)})^n}$ hence $p>1$ necessarely. But is it sufficient? Yes, in fact you can apply ratio criterion to $b_n=2^na_{2^n}$ and see that $\frac{b_{n+1}}{b_n}=\frac{(n+1)2^{n(p-1)}}{n2^{(p-1)(n+1)}}=\frac{n+1}{n}\frac{1}{2^{(p-1)}}\longrightarrow\frac{1}{2^{(p-1)}}$ which is less than $1$ iff $p>1$, as wanted.